# iphone error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before ' 'foo'

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to port the speakhere example into another app and I'm having issues.  I copied all the files, and all the frameworks, but for some reason I get a bunch of compile errors that I've never seen before and thus don't know what to do. The only difference is that i'm not suing IB and so i had to change it slightly.

What does  `error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'foo'` mean?... I get this error multiple times for different files

In my situation the first error is pointing at 'MeterTable'.. a class that includes `<stdlib.h>`,`<stdio.h>` and `<math.h>`.  But those files seem to be importing fine (if i remove them i get more errors)

Any suggestions on how to debug this?

TIA!

EDIT:
I still can't seem to figure it out. I'm literally just copying files from the example into another project. Can someone check it out please ?  [SpeakHerePort.zip](http://dizy.dyndns.org:81/www/SpeakHerePort.zip)   and the original is here [SpeakHere.zip](http://dizy.dyndns.org:81/www/SpeakHere.zip)

Comment: We really need to see the surrounding code. The error is occurring before "MeterTable." That's just the point where the compiler gave up.

Comment: See if this answer helps: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990578/expected-asm-or-attribute-before-crendercontext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990578/expected-asm-or-attribute-before-crendercontext)

Comment: Whenever I get that error, it is simply a missing semi-colon. double check!!

Comment: Since I don't know exactly what's causing the error I just posted the project

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your problem is that you are compiling SpeakHerePortAppDelegate.m, which is an Objective C file, but it is indirectly including MeterTable.h which is a C++ header file.

Rename it to SpeakHerePortAppDelegate.mm (double m) so that it is compiled as Objective C++ and your problem is resolved.

Name all your files .mm and then all your code will be compiled as Objective C++

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the .h and .m in question are built fine with regular target, and the App can run as well.

However after the subset of the files are moved under a static library target, it gets this compile error when the static library is built.

Was stuck for a while & tried the above mentioned techniques, unfortunately they didn't help in my case.

Noted that this error happened only for the NSString*, for e.g.,

- `extern double const kTimeout;        // fine`
- `extern NSString* const kImageType;   // compile error`

After the above analysis & little break, eventually the problem is resolved by adding the the following import to the .h - `"Foundation/Foundation.h"`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like an unfinished declaration, probably in a header file. Search for 'foo' (or whatever the symbol actually is) across all project files, using ⇧⌘F (Edit ▸ Find ▸ Find In Project...) in Xcode, and/or examine the headers you're including where MeterTable is declared. Sometimes the compiler gets confused about the actual location of the error, since header files are frequently #imported into other files, so the problem can be manifest in multiple locations.

Answer (score 1):

This might not have applied to this exact situation, but I had this exact error too, which was caused by a bad forward declaration. In Objective-C, make sure your forward-declares begin with the @ sign - e.g.

```
@class MyClass;
```

Those of us still on autopilot from C++ will forget the @, see that XCode has highlighted class as a reserved keyword, and think all is well with the world. It is not.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you have a syntax error. If you paste the code in question, it's easier to debug.

Comment: Well the strange part is the fact that Even when I takeout any custom code, I still get errors, and its errors from files that I simply copied from the example, not even copoy/paste but the entire files.  So Its almost like its something i'm missing as a project settup. But other then importing all the same frameworks I dont know what else it can be

Comment: If it was an error from some specific file i'd post the source, but its the same error spanning multiple files which all work fine in the example

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar scenario to some of the posts above. I'd written a C++ class based off of the examples in the Audio Queue Services documentation, and had this compilation issue in a test project. This post helped a tremendous amount.

Today, I'm incorporating the C++ class in my project, and got the build error again. In my scenario, I had to also set the type (using the "Get Info" window) to **sourcecode.cpp.objcpp** for the objective-c class that was calling my C++ class.

Comment: oddmeter's answer worked for me, and I think it's the most correct answer in this case. Set the file type to sourcecode.cpp.objcpp.