# iphone error when unit testing: Expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unit-testing

I get the following error when I try to build (Build->build) a unit test. My unit test is a logic test (it does not run on the device).

Things that are probably related to my problem are:
I am using libxml2 and a wrapper around it (which I found at cocoawithlove).

This wrapper has some C functions defined (it is not an Objective C class with `@interface` and `@implementation`). 
The function I am using (and on which the error is occuring) is

```
NSArray *PerformHTMLXPathQuery(NSData *document, NSString *query);
```

The strange thing is that all works perfectly well, when I build my application and run it in the simulator. However when I try to run my unit test, I get this error:

```
/Users/me/XCodeWorkspace/MyProject/XPathQuery.h:15:0 Expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token in /Users/me/XCodeWorkspace/MyProject/XPathQuery.h
```

There are some related questions here, but none of them seems to solve my problem.
In particular:
[iphone error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before ' 'foo'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990906/iphone-error-expected-asm-or-attribute-before-foo)
But here some c++ code should be included.

Thank you for help.

Comment: You can also use LLVM instead of GCC. Nice and clearer error messages!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to change the filetype of my files (I tried several different things and none of them helped) I decided to rewrite these files as Objective-C files with methods instead of functions. 
This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the .h and .m in question are built fine with regular target, and the App can run as well.

However after the subset of the files are moved under a static library target, it gets this compile error when the static library is built.

Was stuck for a while & tried the techniques [from another post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990906/iphone-error-expected-asm-or-attribute-before-foo), unfortunately they didn't help in my case.

Noted that this error happened only for the NSString*, for e.g.,

- extern double const kTimeout; // fine
- extern NSString* const kImageType; // compile error

After the above analysis & little break, eventually the problem is resolved by adding the the following import to the .h - "Foundation/Foundation.h"

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the compiler is trying to compile your file as C code and not Objective-C code.  It's seeing something strange like `NSString`, which isn't part of the C language, so it's barfing at you.

If you change the file to Objective-C or Objective-C++, it should work.  (You can do this be getting info on the file and changing the source type)

Comment: My filetypes are set to Objective-C. When I change the filetype to C (and select my application as the active target) I indeed get the same error. But when I take the working setup (with filetypes set to objective-C) and I switch the target to my LogicTests.octest I get this error. I also get a "warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/XPathQuery.h' of type sourcecode.c.h for architecture i386." Does anybody have an idea? Thanks for everything!

Comment: I tried to include these two files (which can be found at: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html) into some of the sample projects. When I include into iphoneUnitTests sample project I get the same error when I hit build. However when I include them into a project without tests, there is no such error when I compile. The unit tests (logic tests that do not run on the device) are tied to the compilation... Is there any chance to include these wrapper files? Or: Do I have to rewrite them as true Objective-C files with methods instead of functions??