# UIImageView Error?

Tags: uiimageview, uibutton

I would like to make a image appear. So I added the code.

```
myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
```

I substituded it with my backgrounds name. but when ever I try to build I get this error.

```
: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'Screen'
```

could you help me with this error?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is a UIImageView error. Please check the below Link:
[iphone error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before ' 'foo'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990906/iphone-error-expected-asm-or-attribute-before-foo)

If you think it is a UIImageView error means, please try the below code:
    If you have a png file named as "example.png". In your interface builder if you have UIImageView and outlet for that imageview in the view controller.h.

```
UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
 cell.myimageView.image=img;
```

Suppose you want to add the imageview programatically to your view means:

```
UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```