# Switching from Windows to Linux causing error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iphone error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘ 'foo’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990906/iphone-error-expected-asm-or-attribute-before-foo)

Error is at class Sale? 
The program was working fine until I swtiched from coding in visual studio to geany in linux. Im guessing the compiler is why, but im not sure what needs changing?

```
#ifndef _SALE
#define _SALE

class Sale
{
private:
    std::vector<double> itemPrices;
    std::vector<std::string> itemNames;
    double subTotal;
    double bfrDscnt;
    double total;
    double tax;
    double discntORshipping;
    int type;
    int size;
public:
    Sale();
    void itemizePrices( std::string, double );
    double getTotal();
    double getTax();
    double getSubTotal();
    void makeSale(int);
    void addTax();

    virtual void process_payment();
    virtual void print_payment();
    void print_sale(int);
};


#endif
```

Comment: "Before"? Before what? Which line produces the error?

Comment: How do you compile this? Where's the other code? Which line throws an error?

Comment: Well strangley the .cpp for Sale compiles fine. Its only the .h files that are getting this error. Should I post my .cpp for sale too? The error is on line 4 which is at class sale {.

Comment: Look at the column of "Related" questions to the right.  It's filled with questions asking about the same error message.  Have you read the answers?

Comment: Are you trying to compile the .h by itself? Compile the .cpp only, which should `#include` the .h file.
Perhaps your compiler assumes a C program based on the .h extension, and the class keyword is invalid.

Comment: We don't know what the error is, what compiler you're using, or much of anything else.  I'd say you've got zero chance of anyone else figuring out what you did wrong.

Comment: Some things: `_SALE` is a reserved identifier that you should not be using in your code. You are missing the includes for `<vector>` and `<string>`. Other than that there is nothing obviously wrong with the code.

Comment: I briefly thought it might be a line end problem (Windows uses CR-LF, Linux uses just LF), but g++ seems to handle Windows-style line endings.

Comment: @TheNodeCommode: Should you post the code you're actually compiling? ***Yes.***